# Get file name from document library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, csom

I have a document library named **DocLibrary**.
Inside that, I have created few folders. Each folder have 3 another folder. Inside that, I store the specific files.
Example: **DocLibrary > NF1> Communications**,
where DocLibrary is the document library, NF1 is the folder inside DocLibrary and Communications is the folder inside NF1.

Now I want to give the download link to a particular file inside the **Communications** folder sorted by modified date.
I am facing problem on how to goto Communications folder and then select file name.

I am using JavaScript for that.

Right now I am using the below code.
But I am completely new to this and have limited ideas on How to approach.

```
    function test1()
{
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('DocLibrary');

    alert(list);
    var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
    query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl('/DocLibrary/NF1/Communications/');
    allItems = list.getItems(query);
    alert('hi');
    context.load(allItems);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),   Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

function success()
{
    var fileUrls = '';
    var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
    while(ListEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var _contentType = currentItem.get_contentType();
        if(_contentType.get_name() != 'Folder')
        {
            var File = currentItem.get_file();
            if(File != null)
            {
                fileUrls += File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '\n';
            }
        }
    }
    alert(fileUrls);
}
function failed(sender, args) {
    alert('failed. Message:' + args.get_message());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("DocLibrary");
var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
var caml = "<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></View>";
query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl("/DocLibrary/NF1/Communications/");
query.set_viewXml(caml);
var allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, File)');
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),   Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));

function success() {
    var fileUrls = "";
    var ListEnumerator = allItems.getEnumerator();
    while(ListEnumerator.moveNext()){
        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
        var File = currentItem.get_file();
        if(File != null)
            fileUrls += File.get_serverRelativeUrl() + '\n';              
        }
    }
    alert(fileUrls);
}

function failed(sender, args) {
    alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}
```

Comment: Thanx Amal. I tried that code. Its giving error : "Value doesnot fall withing expected range"

Comment: in the last line of the function ie: 
context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),   Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));

Comment: Remove `this` from `this.success` and `this.failed`

Comment: did that. now its like this: context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, success),   Function.createDelegate(this, failed));

still the same error.

Comment: Ok. Change `query.set_folderServerRelativeUrl("/NF1/Communications/");`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value using REST service use following URL format

> http://SiteURL/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/fol1/fol2')/Files?$orderby=TimeLastModified desc

```
function FetchAllFiles() {
$.ajax({
    url:"http://SiteURL/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents/fol1/fol2')/Files?$orderby=TimeLastModified desc" ,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function (data2) {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: Thanx Ravin. Can you give a sample example. Where I have to put this code?

Comment: @MahatmaAladdin Sample code updated in answer